# Re-execute a program after machine exception

Tags: c++, windows

I have a pre-compiled exe (native C++11) which crashes (access violation error) at some point in iterative process. I can not afford debugging it and re-compile it again for now.

I thought of a dirty solution. I will make another program that is responsible for executing that exe and when it stopped working, I simply re-execute it again.

Is it possible? How can I know that the program was stopped?

Note: I am on Windows and doing development using MSVS.

Comment: `CreateProcess` returns a handle that you can query doesn't it?

Comment: should I  WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE ); ?  Is it the case when application crashed ?

Comment: should be easy to read the documentation and knock up a little test

Comment: Thanks for your help, I could reach a solution using your note.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution with help of @Richard Hodges.

Make a new program with the this code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main(int argc, const char**argv) {
    while (true) {
        TCHAR ProcessName[256];
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        wcscpy(ProcessName, L"FaultyProgram.exe");
        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
        // Start the child process. 
        if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
            ProcessName,        // Command line
            NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
            FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,              // No creation flags
            NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
            NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
            &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
            )
        {
            printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
            return 0;
        }

        // Wait until child process exits.
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

        // Close process and thread handles. 
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the most important part is to disable UI Error message when a program crash by changing this value in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
"DontShowUI"=dword:00000001
```

instead of:

```
"DontShowUI"=dword:00000000
```